# how to implement hotkeys in jsf / richfaces xhtml

Tags: jsf, richfaces

This seems like a very simple thing but I've searched and can't find how to do it.

In richfaces/jsf I want to implement some hotkeys on a simple form, eg:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" width="500">
    <h:outputLabel value="User"/>
    <h:commandButton id="userAdd" value="Add" action="staffNewUser"/>
    <h:commandButton id="userEdit" value="Edit" action="staffEditUsers"/>
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

I've tried a bunch of things to get a hotkey to work including:

```
<rich:hotKey key="alt+ctrl+u" >
    <rich:componentControl target="userAdd"  operation="click"/>
</rich:hotKey>
```

Nothing works. Any ideas would be appreciated. (BTW, I am also not finding any docs for the "key" target in hotkey and would appreciate a pointer on where that might be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `enabledInInput` attribute which is necessary when using `<rich:hotkey/>` for input components. So what you should have is

```
<rich:hotKey key="alt+ctrl+u" enabledInInput="true">
    <rich:componentControl target="userAdd"  operation="click"/>
</rich:hotKey>
```

Further reading:

- [Richfaces 4 vdl documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.2.X/4.2.2.Final/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension.html#sect-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension-richhotKey)

EDIT: You really don't need the component control. You can use the `onkeydown` event of the hotkey directly:

```
<rich:hotKey onkeydown="#{rich:element('userAdd')}.click();return false;" preventDefault="true" key="alt+ctrl+u"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The example you reference of displaying a popup does work. However, in my case, the button isn't being clicked or, more precisely, the action that the button takes isn't happening. (Also, the enabledInInput doesn't (shouldn't) make any difference since there are no input fields on this page.) Thanks for the pointer to the reference; I hadn't come across that page before.

Comment: My simple minded brain thanks you very much. That works although it seems that browsers have a lot of hotkeys already define. :(

Comment: @wjr - it's a known issue in RF that's probably messing with you. `preventDefault` doesn't work in Chrome and IE10. Also please accept the answer if it works for you